# D3.js bubble map: Cx and cy attribute function can't read lat and lon coordinates

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Coming across an error that didn't happen in a previous bubble map I've made. I used the same code but just switched in new data in the same structure, including the lat and lon coordinates.

This is the error in the console:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null
at SVGCircleElement.<anonymous> (bubbleMap_top_100_gun_dealing_cities.html:108)
at SVGCircleElement.<anonymous> (d3.v4.min.js:2)
at ut.each (d3.v4.min.js:2)
at ut.attr (d3.v4.min.js:2)
at bubbleMap_top_100_gun_dealing_cities.html:107
at Object.<anonymous> (d3.v4.min.js:2)
at k.call (d3.v4.min.js:2)
at XMLHttpRequest.e (d3.v4.min.js:2)
```

This is the part of the code in question:

```
      var bubbles = svg.append('g')
      .attr('class', 'bubble')
      .selectAll('circle')
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append('circle')
      .attr('cx', function(d) {
        return projection([d.lon, d.lat])[0];
      })
      .attr('cy', function(d) {
        return projection([d.lon, d.lat])[1];
      })
```

My previous map uses the same code and has no such issue.

The circles do draw in the corner of the page if I try:

```
       .attr('cx', function(d) {
        return projection([d.lon, d.lat][0]);
      })
      .attr('cy', function(d) {
        return projection([d.lon, d.lat][1]);
      })
```

Any ideas?

UPDATE: Had an empty value in the CSV! Doh.

Comment: You just have 1 object with empty values, filter it out: https://jsfiddle.net

Comment: I had a feeling it was the CSV! Fixed it. Thanks! :)

Comment: remove the `return` statements inside your `data.forEach()`. How do you prevent that larger circles mask the smaller circles, you do not sort the data?

Comment: The data is sorted in the CSV via Excel. And the bubbles are transparent.